# PHP can't connect to remote MySql Database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to connect to an MySql Database on my external webserver using PHP.

```
<?php
      $host = "######.manitu.net";
      $port = 3306;
      $dbname = "######";
      $username = "######";
      $password = "############";

      try {
          $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
          
          echo "Connection successful";
      } catch (PDOException $e) {
          
          echo "Connection Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
      }

      $db = null;
    ?>
```

My puplic website has no problem connecting https://build.personalitylib.com/sql.php but my localhost (using XAMPP Apache) won't connect

> Connection to database failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection
> attempt failed because the remote site did not respond properly after
> a certain period of time, or the connection established was incorrect
> because the connected host did not respond

I tryed setting the `bind-address` to `0.0.0.0`

Comment: This may be a firewall issue on the web server.

Comment: More than likely the database server does not accept external connections. That could be due to a firewall, or mysql's configuration. You should check on the server's control panel (assuming it's a hosted server) - if it's possible to enable external connections there's probably a setup screen for that (e.g. in cPanel). If you're unsure, contact the hosting company for support.